# Count empty text fields in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got this response in my Chrome console for a view:

```
$('.checklist-17012').length
5
```

There are five in the view, so that's correct. The problem is that they're all empty, and no matter what I do I can't count the empty ones:

```
$('.checklist-17012[val=""]').length
0

$('.pdf-checklist-17012[val=null]').length
0
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="30954" id="30954" value="" class="checklist-17012 form-control">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no attribute called `val`. Should be `value`

```
$('.checklist-17012[value=""]').length
```

---

```js
console.log($('.checklist-17012[value=""]').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="30954" id="30954" value="" class="checklist-17012 form-control">
```

Comment: Ah, thank-you! I knew it had to be something stupid I was doing.